# How to set image width when adding to a MigraDoc document?

Tags: c#, migradoc

I'm generating a `PDF` file with `MigraDoc`. Now I need to add an image to the `PDF`, but if the image is bigger than the page, it is cut, as if part of it is outside the page. I tried to set the image width to a smaller size, but It's not working properly :

```
var sec = doc.AddSection();
var p = sec.AddParagraph();
var img = p.AddImage(imgFile);             
img.Width = "10cm";
img.LockAspectRatio = true;
```

But in the result `PDF`, it seems its ignoring the width I'm setting, It appears with the same size it was before.

---

Found the solution, it was dumber then I thougt. I was testing in a small console applcation, but I was generating the pdf to "Result2.pdf" and opening "Result.pdf". Sorry.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this post, have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301226/fit-image-onto-one-pdf-page-using-migradoc

Comment: Try doing `img.Width = "10.0cm";` All the documentation I've seen for this uses a decimal, even if it was a whole number.